# porque mi arreglo cuando lo convierto en JSON me devuelve vacío

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Primero declaro la variable global : var pdfJson = [];

Luego tengo mi función que arroja la variable "regShip" y cuando lo imprimo me muestran todos los campos correctamente en particular "arhivoJson".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está cuando intento convertirlo a JSON con JSON.stringify(regShip) y lo imprimo me salen todos los datos, menos el objetivo "arhivoJson" que me sale vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si acaso les detallo mi función.

```
function prepareEmbarque() {
            let nombre = getField('nombre').value;
            let tipodoc = getField('tipo-doc').options.selectedIndex;
            let tipodocValue = getField('tipo-doc')[tipodoc].value;
            let docum = getField('documento').value;
            let tipoent = getField('tipo-entrega').options.selectedIndex;
            let tipoentValue = getField('tipo-entrega')[tipoent].value;
            let distr = getField('distrito').options.selectedIndex;
            let direcc = getField('direccion').value;
            let email = getField('email').value;
            let telef = getField('telefono').value;
            let cupon = getField('cupon-dcto').value;

            regShip = {
                nombre: nombre,
                tipodoc: tipodocValue,
                docum: docum,
                tipoent: tipoent,
                tipoentvalue: tipoentValue,
                distr: distr,
                direcc: direcc,
                email: email,
                telef: telef,
                envio: shipping,
                file: pdfFiles,
                files: pdfFilesJson,
                archivoJson: pdfJson,
                cupon: cupon
            };

            return true;
        }
```

Al final hago console.log(pdfJson) y me arroja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento convertir a JSOn con:
let myJSON = JSON.stringify(regShip);
console.log(myJSON);

Mi console log del JSON para ese campo es vacío:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código que agregar valor a mi array:

```
let file = pdfFilesJson;
                for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                    let archivo = file[i]['file'];
                    let datos = new FormData();
                    datos.append("archivo", archivo);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax/shipmentFile.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: datos,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(respuesta){
                            pdfJson.push({
                                        file: 'security_administrator/views/dist/img/shipment/Anotacion_Inscripción_NEWTECH.pdf',
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: No está vacío. Hay un array con un elemento en el índice `0`  según se aprecia en la primera imagen.

Comment: Hola parece que dentro de la función ```prepareEmbarque()``` no tenes acceso a la variable ```pdfJson```  osea esta fuera de scope. ```nombre``` por ejemplo lo tenes declarado dentro de la función. Donde esta declarada tu variable ```pdfJson``` ?

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el código en donde haces el `JSON.stringify(regShip)` así es mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: la variable la tengo como variable global:var pdfJson = [];

Comment: let myJSON = JSON.stringify(regShip);
                    console.log(myJSON);

Comment: tenes que editar tu pregunta para agregar el código. Dentro de la función ```prepareEmbarque()``` podes hacer un ```console.log(pdfJson)``` y avisa si te imprime algo...

Comment: @jdromero88 si me arroja data que ingreso desde el push, es decir, cuando esta en arreglo está lleno el campo, pero, cuando lo convierto a JSON me devuelve vacío.

Comment: @fernandoantonio podes agregar en tu código la parte donde estas agregando datos a tu array ```pdfJson```? tu codigo se ve bien y deberia funcionar.

Comment: @jdromero88 listo agregado en la parte final del articulo.